# Windows server 2012 network drive redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, networking, windows-server-2012

On windows server 2012, I have a legacy code which specifically refers to `\\network_drive1` numerous time. Is there any solution so I can map 
`\\network_drive1` --> `\\network_drive2` at system level

I have tried to map that in `\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, but that did 
not help me.

contains of `\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

> IP_of_network_drive2   \\network_drive1

Comment: The cleanest solution would be to replace the paths in the code with a configuration value. Otherwise someone's going to end up cursing your name down the road when some system dependency inevitably gets missed when  the server gets replaced. Just fix it the right way now.

Comment: As well as adding or faking a DNS entry, the new server has to be configured to recognize the old name.  I don't remember offhand how to do that, you could ask on Server Fault.  I did find [this article](https://www.puryear-it.com/add-hostname-alias-windows-2008-windows-2012-server) but can't personally vouch for its accuracy.

Comment: ... failing that, and assuming you no longer have the source code for the application, I guess you could try hooking the Win32 API.  Tricky, though.